# Access children in function component without the props parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

i've created a class that looks like this:

```
const Button = ({href, className, rippleColor, type}) => {
... 
}
```

i'm using the component like this:

```
<Button rippleColor={'#ff0000'} type={'primary'} className={'my-4'}>Test</Button>
```

now i want to get access to the props.children of the component without switching `({href, className, rippleColor, type})` to `(props)`

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, simply add `children` to your destructuring,

```
const Button = ({children, href, className, rippleColor, type}) => {
... 
}
```

Comment: Would it also work like so: `const Button = ({href, className, rippleColor, type, ...props}) => {...};` and then within `Button` one may use `props.children`? Not only children, but any other props (other than href, className, etc) can be accessed using `props.` if we de-structure with `...props` in the end, I think.

Comment: @jsN00b Sure you can! You can also destructure only the children and leave the others intact inside props. See [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-hofstadter-zhgbgi)